# How does one only display a button when a build.prop value is true?

Tags: android, android-layout

Well, here's the deal:
I'm creating an app which contains some device-specific settings (in this case sweep2wake), but i need it only to appear if the value in the build.prop *ro.product.device* is saga, pyramid or endeavoru.

I already have a layout file with more buttons in it. (just 3 plain buttons with intents)
When the button appears it is supposed to be an intent to a new activity onclick. (but i can handle that.)

How does one do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    if (System.getProperty("ro.product.device", "bollocks").equals("saga") ||
        System.getProperty("ro.product.device", "bollocks").equals("pyramid") ||
        System.getProperty("ro.product.device", "bollocks").equals("endeavoru")) {
        myDopeButton.setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```